# What does this custom metric function in keras mean?

Tags: keras, loss-function

I was looking at this [capsnet code on github](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/blob/master/capsulenet.py#L116)

And I can't find what does the line no. 116 mean?

```
metrics={'capsnet': 'accuracy'})
```

Can someone please explain this line? As I can't find any such reference in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/metrics/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Document

From Keras model functional API: https://keras.io/models/model/

See **Method** > **compile** > **metrics**

> metrics: List of metrics to be evaluated by the model
>                   during training and testing.
>                   Typically you will use `metrics=['accuracy']`.
>                   To specify different metrics for different outputs of a
>                   multi-output model, you could also pass a dictionary,
>                   such as `metrics={'output_a': 'accuracy'}`.

(source: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py#L786-L791)

---

### What Does it Do?

The line outputs the layer called `capsnet` ([which can be found within the same file](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/blob/master/capsulenet.py#L52-L54)) with `accuracy` metric. The rest is just the same as [the document you provided](https://keras.io/metrics/).

```
.... (The above omitted)
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
mask_1 (Mask)                    (None, 160)           0           digitcaps[0][0]                  
                                                               input_2[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
capsnet (Length)                 (None, 10)            0           digitcaps[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (Sequential)             (None, 28, 28, 1)     1411344     mask_1[0][0]                     
====================================================================================================
Total params: 8,215,568
Trainable params: 8,215,568
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```